# Unicode in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, unicode, oracle10g

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_GETINCOMEENTRY
( idec IN NUMBER := 1
, p_IncomeID     tbl_income.incomeid%type      := 1
, P_Data     Out Sys_Refcursor
, P_Fromdate     tbl_acc_income.Dateeng%Type   := null
, P_ToDate       tbl_acc_income.Entrydate%type := null
)  
is
begin    
  if idec=1
  then
    open p_DATA 
    for 
    SELECT INCOMEID as ID
    ,      INCOMENAME as Name 
    FROM   TBL_INCOME 
    order 
    by     p_IncomeID
    ;
  else 
    if Idec=2
    then
      OPEN P_DATA 
      FOR 
      Select Incomeid As id
      ,      Billno As "¿¿¿ ¿¿"
      ,      Relatedperson As "AccountHolder"
      ,      Incomesourid As "IncomeID"
      ,      Dateeng As"EnglishDate"
      ,      Remarks As "Remarks"
      ,      Amount As "Amount"
      ,      Username As "UserName"
      ,      Entrydate As "EntryDate" 
      from   Tbl_Acc_Income 
      where  Tbl_Acc_Income.dateeng between P_Fromdate and P_Todate 
      order 
      by     INCOMEID
      ;
    end if;
  end if;
end;
```

`BillNo As "¿¿¿ ¿¿"`, is unicode in [NEPALI](http://www.nepali.info/nepali/fonts/) but `oracle` is not returning "¿¿¿ ¿¿" when tried to display in `DataGrid` Header in C#

So please Help.

Comment: You should "accept" answers to questions if and when you found them useful (by clicking the accept icon next to the answer). Otherwise nobody will be very motivated to help you...

Comment: how do you relay the command to the dbms? are you sure that sqlplus and/or the shell you are using do not mangle the nepali code points? have you tried to name the columns using other non-latin code points (you may try for example cyrillic (U+0400 - U+04ff)) ?

Comment: hi @Prayag Upd was this answer helpful to solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question. When the answer helped you, can you accept it by clicking the hollow green check mark next to it?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports the use of Unicode in column names. And the construct listed is known to work. However, there are several places where things go wrong. Living in the Netherlands and working with many foreign languages in Oracle, it was always a pleasure to encounter yet another bug in application or Oracle kernel due to use of Unicode. In Oracle 11.2 most Unicode problems finally have been resolved.

Please check the following possible causes:

## Database UNICODE?

Is your database AL32UTF? Use `select value from v$nls_parameters where name='NLS_CHARACTERSET'`

## Undesired translation between client and server

This is your probably cause.

Is your client correctly configured and does it use the settings needed?

Since C# supports almost the same Unicode as Oracle, always use something like 'DUTCH_THE NETHERLANDS.AL32UTF8' as your client's character set, for instance using NLS_LANG. More instructions can be found in [manual of one of our software packages](http://www.invantive.com/en/doc/invantive-estate/web/index.html?invantive-server-installatie-applicatieserver.htm).

Otherwise Oracle will convert characters out of the value range to something like '?'. Please note that character conversion ONLY takes place when the charactersets on both sides differ. If they are both incorrect but identical, Oracle will not notice and just transfer all characters binary without conversion.

Please update your question to reflect what it is returning instead of the upside down question marks.

This conversion occurs with all data, column names or column contents.

Can you update your question whether column contents outside of US7ASCII range is display also incorrectly or not?

## Client Code

Large parts of client software have not been tested with UNICODE characters. The easiest way to get a SQL application crashing is often to introduce mixed case column names or UNICODE column names. Since your client code is C# and you are probably using ODP.NET for connection, that should not be a problem in your case.

For now, please check that you are running ODP.NET.

## Distributed databases

Oracle distributed databases can also introduce extra problems in addition to client/server character set conversion. There are some bugs involved. Please update question if you use distributed databases.